# ASP.NET Panels disappears

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my code behind I have the following:

```
public void btnDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                
{
    if (sku.Peso == 0)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Validation", 
          "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You can't do that!');</script>", false);
        pnlSKU.Style.Remove("visibility");
        pnlSKU.Style.Add("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else 
        //It does something...
         pnlSKU.Style.Remove("visibility");
     pnlSKU.Style.Add("visibility", "visible");
}
```

In my aspx I have the following inside the panel pnlSKU:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSKU" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden; overflow-x: auto overflow-y: scroll; border-right: black thin solid;
            border-top: black thin solid; z-index: 200; left: 210px; border-left: black thin solid;
            border-bottom: black thin solid; position: absolute; top: 28%; height: 500px;
            background-color: white; width: 900px;">
```

The code in itself is very much longer but It doesn't matter at this point. 
Everytime the condition is met the control panel dissapears completely even If I call the method add to the Style property and put "visible".

Any idea why is happening?

Comment: Question: Why don't you just use pnlSKU.Visible = true; ?

Comment: In quick test of this setup, the panel appears when the button is pressed. Therefore, there must be some other css at play. Use the google developer tools or firebug to identity the css rule that hides the panel.

Comment: HashPsi 
I can see the following above the control panel
`<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpSKU" runat="server" TargetControlID="dummyLink" CancelControlID="btnSalirSKU"
        PopupControlID="pnlSKU"
         BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        Enabled="True">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>`

Could this be the culprit? I dont manage CSS, Bootstrap, etc very well... yet.

Comment: I found the problem,
HashPsi pointed me out to the right direction, there was a css rule in this case called mpSKU that it seems came as hidden as default. So checking the code behind I added the mpSKU.Show(); inside the condition while is true.

Is this AJAX?